Is there a group whose space of ends is infinite and discrete?
I'm only aware of groups with one 1 or 2 ends, or the free groups, whose Cayley graphs are infinite regular trees and therefore their space of ends is a Cantor set, not discrete. Any further examples of groups with different topologies on their end space would be appreciated!

Try to prove that every infinite f.g. group either has 1 end, 2 ends or Cantor set of ends.

Oh, interesting! I was planning on taking a look at the proof that f.g. groups can only have 1, 2 or infinite ends to see if I could infer something about the topology of the ends from there. But then my question is still open for infinitely generated groups...

How do you define ends for groups which are not finitely generated?

Oh, right, we need the finitely generated assumption to know that any Cayley graph of a group has the same ends space. When I asked the question I was thinking of Cayley graphs from potentially infinitely generated groups, and considering their ends space (which I'm gonna guess are then not an invariant of the group?)

Right..............

Why the dots? I think considering non locally finite Cayley graphs is still interesting.

Try writing a comment using only 5 symbols.

@MoisheKohan the space of ends of a group $G$ is the Stone space of the Boolean algebra $(2^G/fin)^G$. This was defined by Specker in 1949 , generalizing the definition of Freudenthal for f.g. groups. It is not viewed in terms of Cayley graphs.

For a f.g. group as you know the space of ends is 0, 1, 2 points or a Cantor. For a non-f.g. group, it is either a singleton or has no isolated point. But even for a countable non-f.g. group it can be a Cantor (e.g. for $\mathbb{Q}\ast\mathbb{Q}$) or be non-metrizable (e.g., for the free product of infinitely many nontrivial groups, or for an infinite locally finite group).

@YCor: Interesting; I did not know about this generalization.
